# How do you use XLOOKUP to find matching values in two columns of different sizes and are on different sheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns, Column A has 1030 rows of data while columns B and C have 492, I want to find all the cells that are the same in columns A and B and if they do match then get the value of C. The problem is that columns A and C are on a different sheet. so far I have this:

[image]

```
XLOOKUP( B1, 'sheet1'!A1:A492, 'sheet1'!C1:C492)
```

I thought this one would work but I get the #VALUE! Error. I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem. Note: I'm using the Microsoft 365 version of Excel

[image]

I added the pictures for reference.

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion I caused, I wanted to show in the pictures how COLUMN A is the same in both sheets and that since they are the same, I wanted to get column C. I decided to add all of it to one sheet and make a table out of it. this is what I have now in terms of my formula:

```
= INDEX(A2:C10134,MATCH(A2,B2:1034,0),3)
```

The 3 represents column C while A and B represent the columns I want to find matching values.

Comment: Your current formula seems correct. `#VALUE!` means formula do not find your lookup value.

Comment: @Harun24hr The problem is that when I ctrl + f a value that I know is in both columns, I see it in both. but when I try the formula it doesn't appear.

Comment: `CTRL+F` may find partial match. If you have any hidden character like extra white space.

Comment: I've seen you post this everywhere, and I think I may have finally figured it out. I posted an answer.

Comment: @CaryBallard my apologies, I re wrote the question with more clarity since my first post was hard to understand

Comment: @CaryBallard I added the pictures for reference. I put dummy data since the real one has my personal info in it.

Comment: The pictures do not show what is in column B or C. And give an exact example what you want an answer to look like, not "value I want." I want to help, but you really haven't given enough information to even understand your problem.

Comment: @CaryBallard my apologies for the confusion I caused, the pictures is to show how the data would look like. I wanted to show how COLUMN A is the same in both sheets and that since they are the same, I wanted to get column C.  I decided to add all the columns into one sheet and make a table out of it. this is what I have now in terms of my formula: = INDEX(A2:C10134,MATCH(A2,B2:1034,0),3). The 3 represents column C while A and B represent the columns I want to match.